# I want to save full session log in text file using php

Tags: php, session

I would like to save full session logs in text per each day. here is my code to create file and save log.

```
session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
        header("location: index.php");

        //Write action to txt log
    $log  = "User: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].' - '.date("F j, Y, g:i a").PHP_EOL.
            "Attempt: ".($result[0]['success']=='1'?'Success':'Failed').PHP_EOL.
            "User: ".($_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']).PHP_EOL.
            "User Type: ".($_SESSION['SESS_USER_TYPE']).PHP_EOL.
            "-------------------------".PHP_EOL;
    //-
    file_put_contents('./log_'.date("j.n.Y").'.txt', $log, FILE_APPEND);
        //exit();
    }

    $expiry = 60;//session expiry required after 30 mins
    if (isset($_SESSION['LAST']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST'] > $expiry)) {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        header("location: logout.php");
    }
    $_SESSION['LAST'] = time();
```

Its not creating any file so can anyone help me to save session login time, logout time & session activity in text file in root directory

Comment: Is there any errors ? Could you add error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true); at the start of your script ?

Comment: try with this, file_put_contents('log_'.date("j.n.Y").'.txt', $log, FILE_APPEND);

Comment: Its displays Warning: file_put_contents(log_31.8.2016.txt) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/auth.php

Comment: Here you go, you don't have the permission to write a file in that directory. What's the server's OS ?

Comment: Its linux server. how to assign permissions in linux i'm not familiar with linux!

Comment: @Varma You need to change the permissions for the destination folder : sudo chmod -R 0755 folder

Comment: @vincenth we give the permission as you said. But it displays the same error as before. Or can u please help me how to save the text file in different folder instead of same folder.

Comment: What command did you execute, and what was the output ?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1449 Aug 31 15:38 auth.php
[root@ecare1 html]     drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Aug 30 19:22 www   drwxr-xr-x 16 root      root  4096 Aug 31 16:08 html

Comment: Go to the directory in which the log file will be stored, and execute sudo chmod 0766 .

Comment: @vincenth Thank you for your help. Its done.

Comment: @Varma Great, what did the trick ? chmod 0766 ?

Comment: @vincenth chmod 0777 did the trick. tried 0766 also but didn't worked.

Comment: @Varma That means you give every user access to write read, delete, etc in that folder containing your sessions! You might just want to change the owner of the folder to the user that runs PHP and reset the mod to 755, so instead of `chmod` you can change it with `chown`. The user that runs php varies between Linux distro a quick google search would help you there.